# HTML5Canvas - context.measureText(whitespace).width is zero

Tags: html5-canvas

I have a piece of code that rely's on correctly measuring the width of the text. Most of the time, I am trying to measure the width of `whitespace` in current font that has been set.

While this generally works - I have seen instances in production logs that the `ctx.measureText(' ').width` was zero.

I did some digging around - The font size is never zero. It is always double digit in px.
I looked at the chromium codebase and it seems that the `TextMetrics` object is always created a new object.

Does anyone know what else could be causing this to be zero ?

Comment: Could you try to set up an [MCVE]? Having to debug something that *sometimes* doesn't work without seeing anything around is near impossible.

Comment: Valid font sizes start at 0.  If you define the font size to be 0 you get a 0 width metric. E.G.  `ctx.font = "0px arial"; console.log(ctx.measureText(" ").width)` will log 0

Comment: Yes but that's not the case - The font size is double digits at least.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why this was happening.

The font that was set in the canvas context was getting downloaded. It was not available to the browser.

Chromium code

```
 const SimpleFontData* font_data = font.PrimaryFont(); 
  if (!font_data) 
    return;
```